# Is there a way to hide specific listview items from the main activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Just wondering if what I'm trying to do is possible. So i have a custom adapter for a listview. It contains a textview and two buttons. I would like one of the listview buttons to remain hidden unless a specific button is pressed on the main activity.

So far I have the listview buttons performing their intended function but I have no idea how I would even begin to get what I'm wanting.

Sorry, for clarification, I have one button completely separate from the listview that is just always there. When I press this button I would like to toggle the visibility of a button that is on each listview item all together. The best example of this that I can think of is having a list of items and a button that can toggle off the 1. 2. 3. 4. that comes in front of each item.

Comment: `View.setVisibility(View.X);`

Comment: Post your custom adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method in your adapter for knowing you have clicked the button from your main activity like this

```
public void buttonIsClicked(){ //in your adapter
buttonhide.setVisibility(visibility?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE); 
}
```

And call this method from your activity on btnclick.
like

`yourAdapter.buttonIsClicked();`

and call this method for notifying the adapter about the change.

```
yourAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged().
```

**or**

You can use an interface for listening to the clicks in main activity and implement that listener in your adapter

Answer (score 0):

Set visibility gone to the button you want to hide by calling code

```
buttonhide.setVisibilty(VIEW.GONE);
```

hide it in `oncreate()` of your activity and make it shown on the button click event by calling code `buttonhide.setVisibilty(VIEW.VISIBLE);`

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code

btnView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: OP is trying to hide listview items not the entire listview.Read the question first.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible to do that.
First have a Model class to back the listview data and keep a flag in that model which indicates whether to show the button in that row's data model. On certain condition change that model's flag and call notifyDataSetChanged() on adapter.

Ex:

```
   class Model{
       String label;
       boolean showBtn;
    }

    in adapter's getView()

       Model model = list.get(position)
       if(model.showBtn){
        btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }else{
        btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }

    in Activity

      disableButton(){
       modelList.get(0).setShowBtn(false);
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
```

This code will hide button in first row

Answer (score 0):

Add a Boolean value in your dataset which represent the Visibility state of the button.

```
public class Dataset {
 private boolean visible;

 public boolean isVisible() {
  return this.visible;
 }
 public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
  this.visible = visible;
 }
//..more items
}
```

Then in your `getView` method of the Adapter check this Boolean value to show/hide the button.

```
 boolean visibility = yourDataset.get(position).isVisible();
  yourButton.setVisibility(visibility?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
```

And when the Button outside of your listview is clicked Update your dataset. And call `yourAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting is: manipulating the visibility of the button declared in the Adapter from the containing **activity**. Simple, put a controlling variable in the activity and pass it a parameter to adapter.

```
Boolean mShowButton; //a controlling variable
void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mAdapter=new MyAdapter(...,mShowButton);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(actionShow );
}
OnClickListener actionShow = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View button) { 
        mShowButton=true;
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mListView.invalidateViews();
    }
};
```

And do this in your **adapter**,

```
Boolean showButton;
public MyAdapter(Context context,   List<String>  myList, Boolean showButton) { 
    ...
    this.showButton=showButton;
}

public View getView(int position, View rowView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    if(showButton){
        mButtonTwo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        mButtonTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```